# Help. automounting raid1 on ext4 fstab

Tags: 22.04

I'm setting up an ubuntu server for 2 hdds with a capacity of 500GB.  assembled raid1 on ext4.  The next step is to configure auto-mounting of raid1 when the OS starts.  Could you help with this from the beginning?  I will be very grateful!